# How do you create a callback with an if statement for multiple changed fields in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a `before_save` callback that only gets run if there have been changes to any (but not necessarily all) of the three fields (street, city, state).  How do you do this?  Thanks

user.rb

```
class User
  before_save :run_test_method, :if => street_changed?

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Option One**

You could create a method like:

```
def ok_to_run_test_method?
  street_changed? || something_changed? || something_else_changed?
end
```

and then use:

```
before_save :run_test_method, :if => :ok_to_run_test_method?
```

Note how `:ok_to_run_test_method?` is a symbol. Not sure if it was a typo or not but in your question you are actually calling a **class** method `street_changed?`.

**Option Two**

Modernise your callbacks a little bit and use the block-style syntax:

```
before_save do
  if street_changed? || something_changed? || something_else_changed?
    # whatever you currently have in #run_test_method
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure if I'd call the block version more modern - I like the readability of the symbol form (when the callback itself is non trivial)

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in one line using a `Proc`:

```
class User
  before_save :run_test_method, :if => Proc.new { |u| u.street_changed? || u.city_changed? || u.state_changed? }

  ...
end
```

Comment: In this case even if the conditions are coupled with && the callback function gets executed even if only the first condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `lambda`:

```
before_save :run_test_method, if: ->(u) {u.street_changed? || u.something_changed? || u.something_else_changed?}
```

Comment: Here's a similar example without the `u` argument: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411308/12484