# Rails Callback: Use if more than once as conditional in a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, callback, conditional-statements

I am using Rails 3.2.19 and am having issues when using more than one `if` as a conditional in a callback.

The following mixed double condition works (evaluates first_condtion and second_condition)

`after_save :after_save_method, unless: :first_condition?, if: :second_condition?`

But if I use two `if` conditions the after_save_method is executed everytime. (It seems like is taking only the last condition)

`after_save :after_save_method, if: :first_condition?, if: :second_condition?`

I  also tried to combine the two conditions with '&&' and that didn't work.

`after_save :after_save_method, if: :first_condition? && :second_condition?`

Why can't I use `if` more than once?

The apidoc has an example with unless and if at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#multiple-conditions-for-callbacks, but does not say anything about not allowing two "ifs."

My solution for this was to pull all the necessary code into a method and only evaluates that method, but I just want to make sure about the `if` stuff.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a Proc for this purpose.

```
after_save :after_save_method, :if => Proc.new{ first_condition? && second_condition? }
```

Comment: if first_condition? executes to true the callback is always executed.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you create a private method that knows about the logic you want:

```
after_save :after_save_method, if: :first_condition_and_second_condition?

private

def first_condition_and_second_condition?
  first_condition? && second_condition?
end
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated by @tristanm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888812/how-do-you-create-a-callback-with-an-if-statement-for-multiple-changed-fields-in) you can do something like this:

```
before_save do
  if first_condition? && second_condition?
    after_save_method
  end
end
```

This is one of the options @tristanm suggested, check his answer if you want another option.

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that adding two separate `if:` conditions doesn't work because what you are passing as an argument to that method is a Ruby hash of options. The second `if:` overwrites the first.