# How should I write multiple condition in after_create callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback

I have a method in model that calls after create

```
after_create :generate_insurer_recovery_invoice, if: :insurance_recovery_batch?
```

How should I write another condition within this callback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a callback with an if statement for multiple changed fields in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888812/how-do-you-create-a-callback-with-an-if-statement-for-multiple-changed-fields-in)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also do this for a shorter readable version

```
after_save :update_offices_people_count, if: -> {office_id_changed? || trashed_changed?}
```

P.S: `->` is a shorthand version of writing `lambda`.

Comment: not sure if this is a version issue, but i needed to put a comma before the "if"

Comment: I do agree, right syntax is `after_save :update_offices_people_count, if: -> {office_id_changed? || trashed_changed?}`

Answer (score 5):

I think this may be usefull to you

You can achive this something like this, from the following post

[Multiple conditions on callbacks](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15773-pitfall-activerecord-callbacks-method-call-with-multiple-conditions)

```
after_save :update_offices_people_count

private

def update_offices_people_count
  if office_id_changed? || trashed_changed?  
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Have better solution with lambda     after_save close_claim_for_unrecoverable, if: lambda {|di| di.unrecoverable? && di.unrecoverable_changed? }

Comment: after_save close_claim_for_unrecoverable, if: lambda {|di| di.unrecoverable? && di.unrecoverable_changed? }

Answer (score 0):

#### Pass an Array of conditions.

The `lambda` or `proc` methods work well but you can also just pass in an `Array` to `if`, like so:

```rb
after_create :generate_insurer_recovery_invoice, if: [ :insurance_recovery_batch?, :active_insurer? ]
```

I'm not sure what version of Rails this was added but take a look at the Rails 7 docs here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#multiple-callback-conditions